# Ionic start give error: There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I'm trying to create a mobile app with ionic and cordova but when I launch the comand

```
ionic start {{appname}} blank
```

after the download npm give me

```
Error with start undefined
Error Initializing app: There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
```

I can see that the download is completed because I can see the generated folders. I followed all the suggest I found on the web like update node and npm but nothing works.
Here are the version of npm, node, cordova and ionic

- ionic 2.2.1
- cordova 6.5.0
- npm 4.4.1
- node 6.10.0

Other little warning:
I don't know why after all the upgrade when i launch

```
ionic -v
```

I've got this:

```
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************
2.2.1
```

even if the cordova version is > 4.2.0 but I really don't think that this is the primary problem. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I'm working on windows 7

Comment: Please! mention your OS Info.

Comment: You're right I'm working on windows 7

Comment: Open cmd as admin and then try to run this command.

Comment: I'm using the gitbash so I'm  working as admin as I kown

Comment: Did You install cordova globally?

Comment: yes I lunched 
npm install -g cordova

Comment: **ionic start myApp blank --v2**, try to run this command.

Comment: And if above mention command not works, run this -- **npm update -g cordova ionic** command in cmd as admin.

Comment: I tried both the solutions but still don't work...it just fixed the warning about the version of ionic

Comment: @Daveus Check out chenbobowu's comment in the link - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1013

Comment: I read all but nothing...I really don t know what the problem is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!
I tried to lunch the command

```
ionic start app blank --verbose
```

and as before it stopped at npminstall. The problem were that verbose doesn't told me the real problem. 
I moved inside the folder downloaded by Ionic and I launch

```
npm install --verbose
```

and here he told me that the problem were the https proxy configuration.
So if the error gave by Ionic is just

```
There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
```

just go inside the downloaded folder and launch

```
npm install --verbose
```

for check the real problem

Comment: This worked! I do not know why but `npm install --verbose` was killed the first time I ran it inside the downloaded folder. It was as if there was a timeout on how long it was allowed to run. I ran it again and it completed successfully. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall all (ionic, cordova, nodejs).
2. Install nodejs LTS version using this URL - https://nodejs.org/en/
3. Install ionic and cordova using this URL - https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/intro/installation/
4. Also Reinstall Git  and when it asks **Adjusting your PATH environment** select **Use Git from the Windows Command Prompt**.
5. When You install ionic and cordova open cmd as admin.
6. Then Run command in `ionic start myApp blank --v2`

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to solve the dependency warning problem

```
cordova -v
```

and then you get a question like :

```
May Cordova anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time?
```

say yes.then fixed warning problem.
then install npm globally

```
npm install -g npm
```

create a app without installing its packages

```
ionic start app --v2 --skip-npm
```

seems ok till now?then

```
cd app
```

install packages

```
npm install --save
```

done!try to start your ionic app

```
ionic serve
```