# Ionic "Error with start undefined" after python3

Tags: python, macos, ionic-framework, npm

When I run `ionic start helloWorld blank`, I receive the following error:

```
Error with start undefined
Error Initializing app: There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
```

The above command worked without error when I tried it last(a few months ago). Now I've tried updating `ionic`, but still same error.

I had recently used Anaconda to get python3. So I'm afraid this might be related to that. I tried an alias (suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748069/how-do-i-switch-back-to-python2-after-anaconda-set-python3-as-the-default)) but still getting the same error.

I've tried downgrading via anaconda, with

```
conda install python=2.7.3
```

but still getting the same error from ionic.

Running `ionic info` provides the following output:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: macOS
Node Version: v9.4.0
Xcode version: Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

Running `npm -v` shows `5.6.0`.

Comment: can you tell us the output of `ionic info`  and `npm -v`?

Comment: @gregory - I added that to the question

Comment: when you updated, did you: (1) brew upgrade node; (2) npm install -g npm, (3) npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org?

Comment: @gregory I dont remember exactly, but npm install -g npm looks familiar

Comment: Can you (re)try those three steps to see what you get?

Comment: @gregory After the first step, I saw this: "Homebrew has NOT installed npm. If you later install it, you should supplement
your NODE_PATH with the npm module folder"

The other 2 steps completed successfully tho. But still same error from Ionic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I still needed to do this after downgrading to 2.7

```
npm config set python $(which python)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and these steps helped me:

1. Uninstall ionic `npm uninstall ionic -g`.
2. Cache clean `npm cache clean --force`.
3. Update npm `npm i npm -g`.
4. Install ionic globally `npm i ionic -g`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I still get the same error from Ionic.

Comment: Okay this will solve your problem then https://stackoverflow.com/a/42933728